# Is there a society for the descendants of Mayflower passenger Francis Cooke?

Tags: genealogical-societies

Francis Cooke ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Cooke), [Mayflower Society](http://www.mayflowerhistory.com/Passengers/FrancisCooke.php)) came over on the Mayflower. Some of the Mayflower passengers have their own societies. Does Francis Cooke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [General Society of Mayflower Descendants](http://www.themayflowersociety.com/) is open to descendants of any passenger on the Mayflower and therefore open to descendants of Francis Cooke. The [Francis Cooke Society](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/Francis_Cooke_Society/) is a society for descendants of Francis Cooke, of the Mayflower;and other early New England ancestry. Members maintain a mailing list and assist each other with research.